# Monitoring memcached flush with delay

Tags: memcached

In order to not overload our database server we are trying to flush each server with a 60 second delay between them.  I'm having a bit of issue determining when a server was actually flushed when a delay is given.

I'm using BeITMemcached and calling the FlushAll with a 60 second delay and staggered set to true.

I've tried using command line telnet host port followed by stats to see if the flush delay is working, however when I look at the cmd_flush the value goes up instantly on all of the host/port combinations being flushed without a delay.  I've tried stats items and stats slabs but can't find information on what all the values represent and if there is anything that shows that it has been invalidated.

Is there another place I can look to determine when the server was actually flushed?  Or does that value going up instantly mean that the delay isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I found a round about way of testing this.  Even though the cmd_flush gets updated right away the actual keys don't until after the delay.

So I connected with telnet to the server/port I wanted to monitor.  Then used gets key to find a key with a value set.  Once found I ran the flushall with a delay between the first servers and this one and continued to monitor that key value.  After the delay was up the key started to return no value.